# Cannot get cookies in Java Spring Boot / Angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cookies, jwt

I am working on a Angular11 frontend app coupled with a Java Spring boot backend.

#### Context

I am trying to create an authentication with cookies with JWT.
To do so I am inspired by

- [JWT refresh token flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726066/jwt-refresh-token-flow)
- [Access token and Refresh token best practices ? How to implement Access & Refresh Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999140/access-token-and-refresh-token-best-practices-how-to-implement-access-refres)

My endpoint `/authenticate` returns a jwt access token and set a jwt refresh token in the cookies (httpOnly).
My endpoint `/refreshtoken` gets the refresh token from the cookies and validates it before generating a new jwt access token and a new jwt refresh token.
Here is the code of my `AuthenticationController`

```java
    @RestController
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowCredentials = "true")
    public class AuthenticationController {
        
            private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
            private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
            private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
            private final static String REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE = "resfreshtoken";
        
            @PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
            public ResponseEntity<JwtAuthenticationResponse> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
                try {
                    this.authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
                }
                catch (DisabledException e) {
                    throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
                }
                catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
                    throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
                }
                final UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
                final String token = this.jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails.getUsername());
                final String refreshToken = this.jwtTokenUtil.generateRefreshToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails.getUsername());
        
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie(REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE, refreshToken);
                cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                // cookie.setDomain("localhost");
                // cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
        
                return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(token));
            }
        
            @GetMapping(value = "/refreshtoken")
            public ResponseEntity<?> refreshToken(@CookieValue(value = REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE, required = false) String refreshToken, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
                Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies(); // ALWAYS returns null
                log.debug("refreshToken {}", refreshToken); // ALWAYS null
                try {
                    Claims claims = this.jwtTokenUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(refreshToken);
                    final String username = claims.get("sub").toString();
                    final String newAccessToken = this.jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(username);
                    final String newRefreshToken = this.jwtTokenUtil.generateRefreshToken(claims, username);
                    CookieUtil.writeCookie(response, REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE, newRefreshToken);
        
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(newAccessToken));
                }
                catch (SignatureException | MalformedJwtException | UnsupportedJwtException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", ex);
                }
                catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                    // user should re-login
                }
    
                  return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
        }
```

On Angular frontend, here are the options I add to my /refreshtoken Http request (`withCredentials=true`)

```
refreshToken(): Observable<AuthenticationResponse> {
        return this.http.get<AuthenticationResponse>(this.apiUrl + 'refreshtoken', { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
            tap(response => LocalStorageUtils.save(LocalStorageKey.JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, response.jwtAccessToken))
        );
    }
```

#### My issue

If I try to reach my endpoint `/authenticate` then `/refreshtoken` from postman, everything works well and I can see the cookie
If I call `/authenticate` from my frontend, I can see the cookie in the response with the header SET-COOKIE (and in the *cookies* tab)
[image]
But then if I call `/refreshtoken` from my frontend, I cannot get the cookies with `request.getCookies()` nor `@CookieValue()` on the backend, **it always returns null** !
**It seems like the cookie is well received on the frontend but not set anywere (I cannot see it in *application* tab -> cookies on Chrome).

Therefore it is not sent with the /refreshtoken request**

If anyone can help or has an idea about what is going wrong, I would be grateful ! I can provide more details about my code if it is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `withCredentials: true` to your `httpOptions` and pass it with `HttpClient` every request. You can also configure it globally with HttpClient and Interceptors.

Comment: I updated my question with some more details. I tried your suggestion and it is a good clue, but it still does not work in my case. My cookie is still not sent with the /refreshtoken request.

Comment: Can you add the `.ts` part for authentication as well?

Comment: You actually put me on the right way. My mistake was to put `withCredentials: true` only for the /refreshtoken request. But actually, I have to put it on /authenticate request as well which allows it to set the cookies in the browser ! thank you !

Answer (score 2):

As @TCH mentioned, for the API which returns the Set-Cookie header we need to set request header with `withCredentials: true`. I also did a similar mistake and I want to highlight this point :-)