# Is the access token with the httpOnly cookie necessary along with the refreshToken?

Tags: reactjs, security, next.js, oauth

I am using access token stored with httpOnly cookie in Next.js app to auth user, I wonder if refresh token is really necessary in this case? As far as I know refresh token is used to re-issue a new access token when my access token expires. The key of purpose is to protect the access token and reduce damage caused by XSS attacks, but when my access token is stored in the httpOnly cookie so there is no reason to use refresh token anymore, right?

Comment: when your access_token expires, you will need the refresh_token to renew it, once you have the new token acquired with the refresh_token (one time utilization) the expired token is useless for you, in the both of cases, worth only once until the expiration.

Comment: @RenanDuarte Will the current refresh token also be revoked and no longer actived if it is reissued with a new refresh token?

Comment: Nope, the actual token, will be revoked when the expiration date is reachead, and then, the refresh token has more time to be used, and to continue using that authentication until the refresh token is not expired, you will be able to use the refresh token to get new acces token, and this cicle will occur indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

Well, the idea is to keep the access token short lived to limit the time a potential attacker can do something malicious. The general idea is described here: [Access token and Refresh token best practices ? How to implement Access & Refresh Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999140/access-token-and-refresh-token-best-practices-how-to-implement-access-refres/63001859#63001859)

Regarding the statement:

> The key of purpose is to protect the access token and reduce damage caused by XSS attacks.

This is actually wrong. The key purpose is to reduce damage in case the access token leaks. You achieve this by making the access token short lived. It does not mitigate XSS by any means.

I believe the answer to question whether you need a refresh token is - yes, you do.

Comment: I don't know why the refresh token is used if the access token is already protected from XSS attacks by the httpOnly cookie, if the access token is leaked it's a subjective cause comes from users. with access token stored in cookie, it is quite more secure than localstorage or sessionStorage, we can set expired time longer such as 1 year so I don't see the effect that refresh token brings

Comment: "access token is already protected from XSS attacks by the httpOnly cookie" - define protected. By having XSS vulnerability I can not steal your cookie, but I can make your browser execute the requests I have intended to execute. So no, the protection is not 100%. Setting expiration time like 1 year is asking for trouble.